# gpasswd and access to a file or directory

Tags: linux

As I understand it if I run the command `gpasswd -A username directoryname` I assign administrator privileges to `username` for the directory `directoryname`. This means that `username` is able to add new members to the group for `directoryname` without root privileges. Does this also mean that `username` belongs to the group or do I need to add `username` to the group using the commands `usermod`, `gpasswd -a` or `gpasswd -M`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, group administrators do not automatically become group members; the list is stored in `gshadow` and inaccessible to NSS. You still need to add them as members separately.

Comment: So if I want an administrator to belong to a group, I would need to add the administrator to the group that has access to the file or directory, is that right? Also what is `NSS`?